# Cannot produce original data after dimension reduction via PCA

Tags: matlab, image-processing, machine-learning, statistics, classification

I have a very large data set that I need to use for classification purposes. But when I would try to use it in MatLab I would get and `out of memory` error. To solve this I tried looking into PCA, as this was the intended solution for such problems.

So in order to better understand PCA and to ensure that I can use the result produced by PCA and the original data interchangeably I wanted to reproduce the original dataset from the PCA scores and coefficients.

I used the following code to get the PCA scores and coefficients and then change it back to the original data set.

```
%all_feats is the original dataset of size 128 x 19882
[n m] = size(double(all_feats));
Amean = mean(double(all_feats));
Astd = std(double(all_feats));
B =  zscore(double(all_feats)); %standardise the data
[COEFF,testy] = pca(B,  'NumComponents',2); %This does not reproduce the same result
%[COEFF,testy] = pca(B); %This works ok, but with values > 0
back = ((B * COEFF) * COEFF') .* repmat(Astd,[n 1]) + repmat(Amean,[n 1]);
```

I found out that when I use `[COEFF,testy] = pca(B);` then `back` is the same as `all_feats` but all `0` in the original dataset have been replaced with extremely small values like `3.517186542012496e-13`. I think since they are so small they might as well be 0 for other purposes. But is there any way to get around this? like get the very same data back.

Also if I want to reduce the dimensions to 2 by using `[COEFF,testy] = pca(B,  'NumComponents',2);` then the `back` looks nothing like `all_feats`. Why is that? Is the data changed in dimension reduction? And can I not use it in place of the original dataset?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Dimension reduction techniques **lose** information. You **cannot** reproduce your initial data, only its "approximation". In fact this can be seen as a kind of **compression**. And similarly to the lossy compression techniques - you cannot recover the exact original data.